# How to do login using angular and laravel api?

Tags: php, angular, authentication, laravel-5

login.component.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">E-mail</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" ngModel>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" ngModel>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    onSubmit(form:NgForm){
        const email = form.value.email;
        const password = form.value.password;
        this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/signin",{
            email: email,
            password:password
        }).subscribe((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
        },
        err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

api.php

```
Route::post('/signin', 'AdminController@signin')->name("signin");
```

AdminController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use DB;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function signin(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) 
        {
            return response(['message'=>'login success!!'], 200);
        }
        else
        {
            return response(['message'=>'Login details are invalid'], 200);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new in angular and In above code I am simply want to login using angular and laravel web API. What happen here I am successfully pass parameter using angular and also successfully got in `AdminContoller` function i.e. `signin` function when I try to print to check the value of email and password then it show successfully but when I try to login via email and password then it always show `Login details are invalid` message. I don't know where am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: First confirm you are getting the correct values at the backend by returning them to the angular client and logging it to the console.

Comment: yes @NobleEugene I am getting correct value. I have already checked.

Comment: Well if the user does exist in the database, then perhaps the issue is from the password. Troubleshoot by getting the user model with the email. Then use the laravel hash::check() method to see if the input  password is equal to the password of the user. See if the hash::check() returns true or false